# How to load HashMap properly from a .yml file?

Tags: java, hashmap, yaml, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to load a HashMap from the config file using the standard Bukkit configuration files API.

HashMap:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> banned = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

This is the way I am trying to get the data:

```
public static boolean isBanned(String uuid) {
    if (Dogends.config.getConfigurationSection("Banned").getKeys(true).contains(uuid)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If the player is banned then it's ok, but when the player is not banned, then it throws a NullPointerException out.

NullPointerException:

```
Could not pass event PlayerLoginEvent to Dogends v1.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:302) ~[cb.jar:git-Bukkit-880a532]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[cb.jar:git-Bukkit-880a532]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:501) [cb.jar:git-Bukkit-880a532]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:486) [cb.jar:git-Bukkit-880a532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerList.attemptLogin(PlayerList.java:439) [cb.jar:git-Bukkit-880a532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.LoginListener.b(LoginListener.java:89) [cb.jar:git-Bukkit-880a532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.LoginListener.c(LoginListener.java:53) [cb.jar:git-Bukkit-880a532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:222) [cb.jar:git-Bukkit-880a532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ServerConnection.c(SourceFile:168) [cb.jar:git-Bukkit-880a532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:744) [cb.jar:git-Bukkit-880a532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:335) [cb.jar:git-Bukkit-880a532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:628) [cb.jar:git-Bukkit-880a532]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:536) [cb.jar:git-Bukkit-880a532]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at me.woulfiee.server.ban.BanCommand.isBanned(BanCommand.java:47) ~[?:?]
    at me.woulfiee.server.ban.BanCommand.onPlayerLogin(BanCommand.java:103) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:300) ~[cb.jar:git-Bukkit-880a532]
    ... 13 more
```

config.yml:

```
Ranks:
   Player:
     Players: []
   Mythic:
     Players: []
   Doge:
     Players: []
   Youtuber:
     Players: []
   Builder:
     Players: []
   Mod:
     Players: []
   Admin:
     Players: []
   Owner:
     Players:
      - d166739c-32d3-4b37-a1be-883be57d736c
Broadcast:
   Interval: 120
Banned:
   d166739c-32d3-4b37-a1be-883be57d736c: "CONSOLE \xa7eHELP"
```

Comment: The statement in your `if` is waaaay too long. Split it up. Pull the config section into a local variable and make sure it actually contains what you expected. This way you will be able to figure out where the NPE occurs. Also, posting the actual error message would provide quite a lot of useful information.

Comment: It is hard to tell when code written this way. I see two possible options Main.config.getConfigurationSection("Banned") or Main.config.getConfigurationSection("Banned").getKeys(true) gets null.

Comment: I added the stack trace. Server throws the exception by the line 47 (if (not by the getConfigurationSection(), but by getKeys(true)...)).

Comment: can you show us an example of your YML file?

Comment: @Kerooker I've just added it

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you wish, you should try the following:

- Make sure your config is not null/exists

  boolean isBanned(String uuid) {

  ```
  FileConfiguration yourConfig;

  //Getting the Banned section
  ConfigurationSection banned = yourConfig.getConfigurationSection("Banned");

  //All the keys inside the banned configuration section
  Set<String> keys = banned.getKeys(false);    //We don't want it to be deep
  if (keys.contains(uuid))return true;    //UUID is on the keys list, so the player is banned
  return false;    //UUID is not on the keys list, so the player is not banned
  ```

  }

I don't believe you actually need the hashmap, unless you're using it for something else

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it still doesn't work. Server throws the exception by the "Set<String> keys = banned.getKeys(false);". If it doesn't have to be a HashMap then what should it be? A list?

Comment: What is the new error it shows?
This is the right way of recovering a list from the config files

Maybe you can edit more code in your original question, because the error is being thrown for another reason

Comment: It throws the NPE out

Comment: But the reason it's throwing the NPE is not the getFromConfig code, it's something else, and I need you to show me the exat lines and order of calling which cause it to happen

Answer (score 0):

[getConfigurationSection](https://jd.bukkit.org/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#getConfigurationSection(java.lang.String)):

> If the ConfigurationSection does not exist but a default value has
>   been specified, this will return the default value. If the
>   ConfigurationSection does not exist and no default value was
>   specified, this will return null.

I'm guessing if there are no users banned, there is no `Banned` section, so `getConfigurationSection` returns `null`, which is why your `getKeys()` call throws a NPE.

So you should first check if the configuration section exists, and only then try to use it.